# IF-ELSE Not Working While Calling a Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, if-statement

I am trying to call a procedure with a MySQL command as an argument. Everything is working perfect, but last procedure call where there has been implemented a conditional statement is behaving badly. The error description encountered when the procedure is called is provided below:

**Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF @CheckExists > 0 THEN
                    set @result= ('done')**

For more information, here i am passing a statement that should have been implemented itself in a procedure (i guess, loops, cursors conditions has to be defined in a procedure in MySQL) and hence an error. But i could not figure this out as the database name (@dbname in this case) has to be passed dynamically and even i tried to make another procedure to make this work i end up with the same error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

```
use test;

drop procedure if exists test;
set @dbname = 'test_qa';-- only for the sake of example. this is to be dynamically done                     


delimiter //
create procedure test(IN sqlCommand text) 
begin

 SET @tquery = sqlCommand;
 PREPARE stmt FROM @tquery;
 EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

end//

delimiter ;

CALL test (concat('SET @CheckExists =(select COUNT(*) from ',@dbname,'.course 
                        where Name = ''Computing'' and Value = ''True'')'));

-- call test ('select @CheckExists');

CALL test (concat('IF @CheckExists > 0 THEN
                set @result = (''done'') 
                else 
                set @result = (''gone'')
                end if'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `IF` (or procedural code at all) in anonymous blocks in MySQL.

Use this:

```
CALL test('SET @result = CASE WHEN @checkExists > 0 THEN ''done'' ELSE ''gone'' END')
```

Comment: Oh yes, thanks a lot. This is working. Also, CALL test('SET @result := if(@checkExists > 0,''done'',''gone'')'); will do the trick.